# System call to open a pdf on Entourage eDGe's E-Reader

Tags: android, system-calls

I am trying to write an app that requires different PDF files to be opened and displayed on the E-Reader side of the eDGe's dual screens while the app is running on the LCD side. I've been using Better Terminal Emulator to cruise around the eDGe's file system but can't seem to find the command that opens PDF files. Does anyone know it or is there even one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer my own question in case someone runs into the same issue.  Using an intent with the action set as ACTION_VIEW, the mime type set as application/pdf, and a pdf file as the data, the Library will handle the intent.